# "cannot be resolved to a variable" compile error

Tags: c#, enums

I'm trying to get my code to check whether or not a certain string is in the enumerated type. This is what I have:

```
public enum CurrencyAmt {twenty(20), ten(10), five(5), toonies(2), toony(2), loonies(1), loony(1), quarters(0.25), 
quarter(0.25), dimes(0.1), dime(0.1), nickels(0.05), nickel(0.05), pennies(0.01), penny(0.01);

private int type;
private double value;

CurrencyAmt (int i)
{
    this.type = i;
}

CurrencyAmt (double i)
{
    this.value = i;
}
}
```

defines my enum type. And the expression

```
(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(CurrencyAmt), inputAt)
```

to check if the string 'inputAt' is in the enum. However, i receive the error CurrencyAmt cannot be resolved to a variable. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `typeof()`? Also `CurrencyAmt` is the name of a type, not an instance.

Comment: The enum definition looks like java, but Enum.IsDefined is a .NET thing i think

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio to compile this? Should be tagged as C# btw

Answer (score 2):

You need a `.class` after `CurrencyAmt`, I reckon:

```
(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(CurrencyAmt.class), inputAt)
```

However, as I don't recognise any other parts of this code snippet from Java, I think the Java version should be:

```
CurrencyAmt.valueOf(inputAt);
```

...which will return the `CurrencyAmt` enum constant that corresponds to the given string or will throw an exception if it's not defined.